# Proving uniqueness of invariant factors in finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am restricting to "finite" abelian groups, and their description in terms of **invariant factors**.

The problem I am considering is the basic one, but in some different way if possible.

Let $C_n$ denotes cyclic group of order $n$. Suppose we have decomposition of finite abelian group as
$$
C_{d_1} \oplus C_{d_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{d_k} \cong C_{e_1} \oplus C_{e_2} \oplus \cdots  \oplus C_{e_l} \hskip5mm (d_i|d_{i+1}  \mbox{ and } e_i|e_{i+1}) 
$$
Is there a direct way to proceed from this decomposition (i.e. without further factoring $d_i$'s or $e_i$'s to show that
$$k=l \hskip5mm \mbox{ and } \hskip5mm  d_i=e_i \hskip5mm \mbox{ for all } i?$$

The books or notes which I saw, mostly pass to prime-power factorization from the above decomposition and use the uniqueness of **elementary divisors**.

My question is simply, can we prove uniqueness of **invariant factors**  for **finite abelian groups** without moving to prime power factorization? If  possible, how? and if not, why?

Comment: Hint: The largest invariant factor corresponds to the exponent of the group. Cancel it (prove that you can!) and use induction.

Comment: How cancellation is possible directly? I don't think it works directly even in abelian $p$-groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what sort of proofs you want to reject. But here is how it can be proved.

Suppose $k\ne l$. Then without loss assume $k>l$;  let $p$ is a prime divisor of $d_1$. Then $\{x\in G\mid x^p=1\}$ has order $p^k$ (left hand side) and at most $p^l$ right hand side. Hence $k=l$. Moreover $p$ divides $e_1$, or we still have a contradiction.

Now argue by induction on $|G|$.  Consider $H=\{x^p\mid x\in G\}$ and see that $d_i/p=e_i/p$ for all $i$.